# How to prompt radio button based on usestate

Tags: reactjs, use-state

My requirement is to prompt certain radio button based on the amount of array for example. If there are 5 item in an array then it will prompt 5 radio button based on the array's productName field.

This is my test data:

```
 const testData = [
    {
      "itemCode": "1",
      "productName": "P1 Item name",
  },
  {
      "itemCode": "2",
      "productName": "P1 Item name",
  }
```

Then it my radio button:

```
<div className={styles.selection}>
    {testData.productName.map((selection, index) => (
      
      <div onClick={() => handleChangeFlavour(index)} key={index}>
        {console.log('EXAMPLE: ', testData)}
        {selectedFlavour === index && <img src={RadioSelected.default} />}
        {selectedFlavour !== index && <img src={RadioDeselected.default} />}
        <span>{selection}</span>
      </div>
    ))
    }
  </div>
```

This method return error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')
```

The reason why do i put testData.productName is because if i dont it will return this error

```
react-dom.development.js:13413 Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {itemCode, productName}). If you meant to render a collection of children,
```

Comment: The error is telling you that there is no testData.productName. Which there isn't because testData is a list.

Comment: Please try to replace `testData.productName.map` with `[...(testData.map(obj => obj.productName)].map(`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's your problem:

```
testData.productName.map((selection, index) =>
```

`testData` is a array which doesn't have `productName`. If you would like to iterate through `testData` you should do this:

```
testData.map((selection, index) =>
```

And, instead of

```
<span>{selection}</span>
```

use:

```
<span>{selection.productName}</span>
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me, But it will return 
uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {itemCode,, productName}). If you meant to render a collection of children, error

Comment: If using the above answer, then please try replacing `<span>{selection}</span>` with `<span>{selection.productName}</span>`.

Comment: @tedeeee Please check the last part of answer again.

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH replacing that WORKS!!! THANK YOUUU – @MajidM